# Is it ideal to transfer variables from the View page to the Controller page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter's MVC to build a form where logged in users can post questions.

I am using a form that allows logged in users to insert data in a mysql table called Questions (table structure is shown below).

**Questions table**

```
______________________________________________
| id   |    User id  | description | category |
|---------------------------------------------|
|1     |      22     |  Car parts  |   12     |
|---------------------------------------------|
|2     |      54     |  Car parts  |   8      |
|---------------------------------------------|
|3     |     112     |  Car parts  |   11     |
|_____________________________________________|
```

Once a user submits the form, the user's id and category_id (from the table below "users table") is inserted into the **questions table above**

**Users table**

```
___________________________________
| id   |    User id  |category_id |
|-------------------------------
|1     |      22     |    12      |
|------------------------------   |
|2     |      54     |    54      |
|----------------------------     |
|3     |     112     |    8       |
|_________________________________|
```

**My controller page code**

```
 $this->load->model('questions_page');
    $data['page_detail']  = $this->questions_page->get_business_page_by_pid($page_id);

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false || $form_validation == false)
        {
            $data['form_value'] = array(
                'country'        => $this->input->post('description'),
                'street_address' => $this->input->post('street_address'),
                'post_code'      => $this->input->post('post_code'),
            );
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }
```

**This is my View page**

```
<input type="text" name="post_code" value="<?= $form_value['description'] ?>">
                    <?php echo form_error("description"); ?>
<input type="text" name="post_code" value="<?= $form_value['street_address'] ?>">
                    <?php echo form_error("street_address"); ?>

   <?php // I gathered some info from the users table below which needs to be inserted into the questions table
    ////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////
    $page_detail->category_id;
    ////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////          
   ?>
```

**My problem**
I have data in the view page in the last line ( **$page_detail->category_id;** ) that I'd like to transfer to the controller page so I can insert it in the mysql table using the **$data['form_value'] = array();** as shown in the controller page.

How do I do this?

Is transferring data from the view to controller safe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your storing the `user id` in question table so need to store the `category id` . because you can join two table with user id so that you can get the category id from user table .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** Your storing the **user id** in **question table** so There is created relationship between two table so you can **join** two table with **user id** so that you can get the **category id** from user table . so no need to store the category id in question table .it's unnecessary . if you store . it's called **data redundancy.**

**2nd :** Guess user id will be get from session .

**3rd :** still you want pass the category_id from view to controller means just use some hidden input

```
 <input type='hidden' name="category_id" value="<?php echo  $page_detail->category_id; ?>" />
```

In controller :

```
$data['form_value'] = array(
                'country'        => $this->input->post('description'),
                'street_address' => $this->input->post('street_address'),
                'post_code'      => $this->input->post('post_code'),
                'category_id'    => $this->input->post('category_id'),
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. very helpful @JYoThI . 

I would still like to insert the $page_detail->category_id; into the questions table. 

How do I transfer it to the controller page? can I do this 'category_id'      => $page_detail->category_id, ?

Thanks :)

Comment: still you want pass the category_id from view to controller means just use some hidden input <input type='hidden' name="category_id" value="<?php  $page_detail->category_id; ?>" > @mark

Comment: Thanks. If I use the inspect element tool on the browser, I can change the value of in hidden input field. Is there an alternative so that the value isnt manipulated? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if you don't want hidden input just `query the database` with the where clause of user id and get the category_id  in controller . @mark

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to do :) but I am not sure how to do it. I've tried this 'category_id' => $page_detail->category_id,  but its not right. Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess "session"  is the only option then ( as the value is saved on server) or you can save it in encrypted format in hidden variable (like encode , deocode , sha , crcp32  ) as no one will understand and if it got manipulated    through a error or ask user again to enter the info.

Comment: Thanks very good advice thanks :). You mentioned query the database where the clause of the user id to get the category_id in the controller. Do i just fetch the data in the controller page? how does it work if you could show me a small example, I'd really appreciate it man

Comment: `select category_id from user_table where id=$_SESSION['user_id'];` @mark hope that you know how build function in modal and return the data to controller .

Comment: ahhh I do a little :S. I've got this so far haha 

$query = select category_id from user_table where id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
  $row = $query->row(0, 'pt_user_id');  @JYoThI

Comment: @JYoThI  - if you if you have time, can you look at this.  $data['form_value'] = array(
                    'post_code'      => $this->input->post('post_code'),
     'category_1'  => 1882,
                );
                $this->load->view('template', $data); --- I'm inserting a fixed number for category_1 in the array data, but its not passing. Am i doing it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152257/discussion-between-mark-and-jyothi).

Comment: Thanks @JYoThI appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

save the value in the input box of type hidden , so the form will get submitted and category value can be fetched at controller

something like below

```
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?= $page_detail->category_id;?>">
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use the inspect element tool on the browser, I can change the value of in hidden input field. Is there an alternative so that the value isnt manipulated? Thanks in advance :)